# Floatmax not defined is stopping me from solving a MIP

Tags: julia, glpk, julia-jump

Basically, I have an MIP completely defined, everything is working, until I attempt to solve via GLPK, when it gives me the following error: UndefVarError: floatmax not defined
I tried defining floatmax as anything, but to no avail. I'm completely stuck. Here's an image of my code and the problem:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72EI7.png)

Comment: Hi Tamir! Please, could you edit the code and error message into your post as text form? Then the content is searchable, and can't disappear later.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an old version of `Compat` installed. Try running `Pkg.update()`. `floatmax` is defined on Julia 0.6 beginning with Compat 1.1.0. I fixed the version requirements here: https://github.com/JuliaOpt/GLPKMathProgInterface.jl/pull/55.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are working under Julia 0.6 and `floatmax` is internally used by the GLPKMathProgInterface.jl package.

Possible solutions are:

1. Swithch to Julia 1.0 (recommended)
2. Install an older version of GLPKMathProgInterface.jl before it was ported to Julia 1.0; release v0.4.2 should be ok
3. Manually add the following definition in the source file GLPKMathProgInterface.jl before include section:

   `floatmax(::Type{Float64}) = prevfloat(Float64(Inf))`

(I have not run it as I do not have Julia 0.6 any more, but it should work; the risk is that even if you fix this some more fixes like this might be needed - so option 3 is not really recommended, but it might work so I am giving it)